# Why doesn't my `.Rprofile` run? (on unix server)

Tags: r

I have problems to start up my R session with a `.Rprofile` on a unix server. When I start an interactive job everything works fine. When I start a batch job, it doesn't (batch jobs are started through TORQUE and distributed across different nodes). I checked `?Startup` but I still don't know what's going on. My `.Rprofile` contains a `print(...)` line just to make sure and I ran the `test-job.r` file below in batch mode. It tells me that I have a `.Rprofile` file at the current working directory and at the user directory (they are the same) and that it contains my `print(...)` code. So why is R not running the `.Rprofile` file on startup?

**.Rprofile**

```
print('Hallo World!')
```

**test-job.r**

```
profile1 = paste(getwd(),'/.Rprofile',sep='')
file.exists(profile1)
if(profile1) cat(readChar(profile1, 1e5))

profile2 = '~/.Rprofile'
file.exists(profile2)
if(file.exists(profile2)) cat(readChar(profile2, 1e5))
```

**output**

```
> file.exists(paste(getwd(),'/.Rprofile',sep=''))
[1] TRUE
> if(file.exists(paste(getwd(),'/.Rprofile',sep=''))) cat(readChar(paste(getwd(),'/.Rprofile',sep=''), 1e5))
print('Hallo World!')
> 
> 
> file.exists('~/.Rprofile')
[1] TRUE
> if(file.exists('~/.Rprofile')) cat(readChar('~/.Rprofile', 1e5))
print('Hallo World!')
```

Comment: Sounds like you are running R with the command argument `--no-init-file` or `--vanilla`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Intro to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line):

> note that R CMD does not of itself use any R startup files (in
>   particular, neither user nor site Renviron files)

I interpret that as meaning BATCH mode doesn't read the `.Profile` file.  If you want it, I guess you need to explicitly `source` it in `test-job.r`.